# Нужна помощь с наследованием

Tags: ооп, наследование

Мне нужно создать класс `Date`для работы с датами, и к этому классу применить наследование.

У меня была идея создать класс `Calendar`, унаследоваться от моего класса `Date`, и реализовать методы такие как "добавить события", "получить предстоящие события" и т.д.

Проблема в том, что мне кажется, что я неправильно применяю принцип наследования, может все-таки класс `Calendar` не очень подходит чтобы наследоваться от `Date`? Что вы можете посоветовать ?

Comment: «может все таки класс Calendar не очень подходит что бы наследоваться от Date?» – тут Вы совершенно правы, не подходит.

Comment: А что тогда мне лучше делать в данной ситуации? чего я не вижу?

Comment: Может унаследовать **Event** от **Date**?

Comment: Можно. Хотя и тоже не очень подходит...

Comment: @Mihail Krasilnikov  О каком языке программирования идет речь?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Для данной лабораторной работы применяется C#.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, об архитектуре же, судя по вопросу. А как язык влияет на ответ?

Comment: От `Date` может наследоваться например `DateOfBirth` , у которого может появиться дополнительно метод `getOld()`, например. Если задача - просто применить правильно наследование, этого хватит, если нет - приведите полную задачу.

Comment: Календарь **не является** разновидностью даты, так что о правильном наследовании говорить не приходится.

Comment: Да тут всё просто. Инкапсуляция - значит должны быть поля. `День`, `Месяц`, `Год`. Наследование - значит нужно придумать такую штуку, у которой тоже есть `День`, `Месяц` и `Год` и ещё что-то своё. Придумываем DateTime, у которого будут `Часы`, `Минуты`, `Секунды` дополнительно к унаследованным полям.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр Мне однокурсник предлагает создать класс `Ежедневник`, который будет наследоваться от моей реализации класса `Date`, но у меня в голове не укладывается, как Ежедневник может являться датой?

Comment: Ежедневник, это уже другая связь - не наследование, а агрегация множества. Приведите полную задачу в вопросе, и @Sergey правильно расписал матчасть)

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр Вот в этом и есть проблема, изначально задание звучало вот [так](http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1135746.html) , и когда на практическом занятии обсудили наследование, преподаватель сказал, > примените к своим классам наследование.

Comment: @Mihail Krasilnikov `Создать класс Date для работы с датами` вот что же вы в вопросе этого не написали) Когда программисты видят `реализовать класс Date` у них в голове класс **определённой** даты, то есть у которой есть методы `getMonth()` `getDay()` например. А у вас задание **библиотека для работы с датами** - там полёт для творчества большой, и наследование можно применить по-разному. Например `Calendar` и метод `getCalendar()` в нём решат задачу, но можно много ещё придумать... Поправьте лучше вопрос)

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр Прошу прощение)

Answer (score 3):

Зайдите на [сайт Чарльза Петцольда](http://www.charlespetzold.com/dotnet/index.html) , известного автора многих книг по программированию для Windows. Скачайте по данной ссылке его свободно распространяемую книгу **NET Book Zero**.

В этой книге как раз последовательно определяется класс `Date` на языке C#, а затем в последующих главах этот класс наследуется классом `ExtendedDate`.

Вы можете почерпнуть оттуда идеи, например, какие методы определить в своем производном классе независимо от того, как вы его назовете, и даже если вы позаимствуете определения классов, это все равно для вас будет полезно, так как вы изучите представленный в книге материал.

Вы даже в своей лабораторной можете дать ссылку на эту книгу в разделе "Используемая литература". То есть у вас будет солидный результат, показывающийя, что вы, действительно, проделали большую работу.:)

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что можно обойтись агрегацией. Но это мое субъективное мнение.

```
class Date{ }
class Calendar
{
     private Date d;
     //и тд
}
```

Comment: Для Календаря, да. Но человеку нужен именно пример наследования.

Comment: Как правило, наследование выражает отногение "является".Что-то не приходит в голову класс, который может являться датой...

Answer (score 0):

Понимаете, все зависит от задачи которую решает ваша программа. Ее классы, интерфейсы и прочее образуют систему типов. Работая сообща типы должны решать общую задачу. Так вот ООП, это один из подходов к организации систем типов и следовательно программ.

Таким образом, вам нужно сначала придумать задачу которую будут совместно решать ваши классы, но так чтобы там было наследование. Вполне возможны задачи, где календарь будет наследоваться от даты, почему нет.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае найболее правильно будет использовать агрегацию, как уже говорили выше, если у вас есть специальный класс для дат, можно просто сделать его полем класа Event.

```
class Event {
   private Date date;
            ... field1;
            ... field2;
}
```

Наследование тут вообще не в тему, очевидно что событие никак не является подмножеством даты.